# Having trouble with file output

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I want to be able to read in 20 random names from the file and put them into a new file. How do i go about this?

```
public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // Read in the file into a list of strings
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textfile.txt"));
        //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while( line != null ) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        // Choose a random one from the list
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
        {
           int rowNum = r.nextInt(lines.size ());
           System.out.println(lines.get(rowNum));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("randomNames.txt"))) {

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       int rowNum = random.nextInt(lines.size());
       writer.write(lines.get(rowNum));
       writer.newLine();
    }
}
```

If you need to check if some number was already used, add it to a set:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("randomNames.txt"))) {
    Set<Integer> usedNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(20);
    Random random = new Random();
    int addedCount = 0;

    while (addedCount < 20) {
        int rowNum = random.nextInt(lines.size());
        if (usedNumbers.add(rowNum)) {
            writer.write(lines.get(rowNum));
            writer.newLine();
            addedCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

To check if there is another name with same first character:

```
private static void containsNameWithSameFirstCharacter(Collection<String> names, String name) {
    for (String anotherName : names) {
        if (anotherName.charAt(0) == name.charAt(0)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you do:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    Set<String> usedNames = new HashSet<String>(20);

    while (usedNames.size() < 20) {
        int rowNum = random.nextInt(lines.size());
        String name = lines.get(rowNum);
        if (!containsNameWithSameFirstCharacter(usedNames, name)) {
            usedNames.add(name);
            writer.write(name);
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. and you talked about if i need to check if a number was used.. well i need to make sure there are no duplicate names with the same first letter. how can i go about this?

Comment: Get a random number, get a name using this number, check if is not a duplicate name (using a collection of used names). If it is not a duplicate name, add to the collection. Do it until collection reaches 20 elements.

Comment: But it cant be the first letter. Like if Mary is already in the list then Mark can't be